# storyboard appdelegate changes for multipleview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

created a singleview application with storyboard.
Added three viewcontrollers apart from the one view present by default,Now how to refer to this ViewController programmatically from the AppDelegate did finishlaunchingoptions function? I've created 3 view controller classes and what are the changes i should do in appdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems as if a tutorial would make sense so you could learn how storyboard based development in iOS 5 works. 
A great one i found is [this one written by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1).